# Exclude pseudo elements from hover

Tags: css, hover, pseudo-element

How do I exclude pseudo-elements like `:before` and `:after` from being changed by selectors like for example: `:hover`?

Maybe there's some sort of 'main pseudo element' that I'm not aware of?

I've tried using CSS3 `:not()` statement but this didn't work.

Using: `.facebook:hover:before {color: black;}` works fine, but I'm sure that there's a better solution.

---

**Example**:
I want the Facebook logo to remain black and change the texts color.

```css
body {
  background: #F7F7F7;
  margin: 0px;
}
.share-button {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 12px 24px 12px 12px;
  transition: color 1s;
}
.facebook:before {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  width: auto;
  content: '\f09a';
}
.share-button:hover {
  color: #374D8D;
}
```

```html
<button class="share-button facebook">
  Share on facebook
</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is not that the pseudo-element is being "matched" by the `:hover` selector *per se*, but that it is inheriting the `color` property from the corresponding CSS rule on the element.

That is the reason why you need to set it explicitly on the `:before` pseudo-element — you cannot block inheritance using a selector, or using a style on the parent or originating element.

Comment: Setting the color in `.facebook:before` worked fine!

Comment: @Maarten1909: Indeed - I just noticed that there's only a `color` declaration on the `:hover` rule.